# Eloquent query to return the sum of an array grouped by the values in a collecion

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, twig

I'm building an application that uses slim, twig, and eloquent. On one of my pages, I'm showing a group of items first split into two groups, and then further split into group by category. Each item has a weight. I'm outputting the total weight of all the items from the first split. I'm outputting the name of each category once from the second split. Now I'd like to get the total weight of of only the items in that category and list it under that category name.

This is from the route:

```
$userId = $app->auth->id;

$collection = collect($app->item->where('user_id', $userId)->get()); // All items from the current user

$totalWeight = $collection->sum('grams');

$pack = $collection->filter(function($gear) { // All items with status 1 from the current user
    if ($gear->status === 1) {
        return true;
    }
})->sortBy('category');

$storage = $collection->filter(function($gear) { // All items with status 0 from the current user
    if ($gear->status === 0) {
        return true;
    }
})->sortBy('category');

$app->render('user/gear.php', [
    'pack' => $pack,
    'storage' => $storage,
    'totalWeight' => $totalWeight
]);
```

This is from the view:

```
<div class="pack">
    <header class="pack__header">
        <h2 class="pack__header__title">Backpack</h2>
        <span class="pack__header__weight">Total Weight: {{ totalWeight|outputWeights(totalWeight) }}</span>
    </header>

    {% set currentCategory = null %}
    {% for item in pack %}
        {% if item.category != currentCategory %}
            <h3 class="categoryName">{{ item.category|getCatName(item.category) }}</h3>
            {% set currentCategory = item.category %}
        {% endif %}

    <div class="item">
        <ul class="item__lineOne">
            <input type="checkbox" form="itemCheck" name="ID of the item" value="selected">
            <li class="item__lineOne__name">{{ item.name }}</li>
            <li class="item__lineOne__weight">{{ item.grams }}</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="collapse">
            <ul class="item__lineTwo">
                <li class="item__lineTwo__description">{{ item.description }}</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="item__lineThree">
                <li class="item__lineThree__url">
                    <a class="item__lineThree__url__link" href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.url }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="modifyItemButton">Modify</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I also have a file with some Twig_SimpleFilters if I need to employ some code during the foreach in the view. I'm just not sure where or what is an effective way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can simplify your collection methods:

   ```
   $pack = $collection->where('status', 1)->sortBy('category');
   ```

   instead of filter.
2. you don't need sortyBy, use `groupBy` instead:

   ```
   $pack = $collection->where('status', 1)->groupBy('category');
   ```

   and then use `sum` in your template for each category:

   ```
   {% for category,items in pack %}
     <h3 class="categoryName">{{ category|getCatName(item.category) }}
     <br>weight: {{ items.sum('grams') }}
     </h3>

     {% for item in items %}
       <div class="item"> ... </div>
     {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I had never seen multiple arrays passed into a single for and had no idea that the group could be targeted like that without being specifically named in the route. Off to study documentation. Thanks.